# how to bypass the local connection in swift

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

i just want to test my local web service call to check my data from server. i don't know to make connection to local host in swift here i provide my sample code which i practiced

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/EntityList")!)
 var theConnection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!

}


func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace) -> Bool {
    return true
}

  func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) {

    if (challenge.protectionSpace.host == "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/EntityList") {

        challenge.sender!.useCredential(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge.autoContentAccessingProxy() as! NSURLCredential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

    }


}
```

my log statement is

```
  error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not    connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc9705525a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo=   {_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:9000/api/v1/EntityList,   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:9000/api/v1/EntityList,    _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61,    NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.})
```

Comment: unless your app runs its own webserver... i dont think this is what you want, do you not mean a server on your local network?

Comment: you need to find out what the ip of your server is, then replace `localhost` with the ip like `http://192.168.1.95/api/v1...`, `localhost` basically means "this device" so you were trying to connect to a server that is on the same device, and not on the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that API request is not able to find the address that you have given.

The address that you have given is

```
http://localhost:9000/api/v1/EntityList
```

You have to change this to

```
http://domainName.com/api/v1/EntityList
```

where domainName.com should be name or DNS of the server in your local network. This can be your PC or someone else PC which has the capability of acting as a web server.

Another thing that you have to take care is that you have to bypass NSTranportSecurity token as iOS 9 doesnt support unsecured requests. In short your request should be to a server which supports HTTPS

You can bypass this by adding the following code into plist

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>

  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

If you need more information on this then you can visit the following link

[LINK](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

[LINK 2](http://www.soortapp.com/ios-9-nsapptransportsecurity-tutorial/)

Hope this helps you....

Comment: Also happens I couldn't connect via domain name. I restarted mac and phone which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See you have to make a call through your server or system IP address

for examples 
Your have to replace this

```
http://localhost:9000/api/v1/EntityList
```

To this

```
http://<your server ip address>/api/v1/EntityList
```

And make sure your firewall is not blocking the port 80 there are many way how to unblock it just google..

if you get **NSTranportSecurity** error then you have to add this lines to your **Info.plist** file because from iOS 9 it doesn't support unsecured requests.

my **Info.plist** file snapshot is attached below

[image: SNAPSHOT]

I would suggest you do this way as this is more secure than the above method

[image: SHAP]